# Difference between express.Router() vs multiple express() object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know using the new express 4 router we can organize multiple route paths into different files like this:

```
// In cars.js
 const router = express.Router();
 router.get('/brands', function(req, res) { ... });
 router.get('/models', function(req, res) { ... });
 module.exports = router;

// In animals.js
const routerTwo = express.Router();
routerTwo.get('/domestic', function(req, res) { ... });
routerTwo.get('/wild', function(req, res) { ... });
module.exports = routerTwo;

// In main.js
app.use('/cars', router);  // matches `/cars/brands`, `/cars/models`.
app.use('/animals', routerTwo); // matches `animals/domestic`, `animals/wild`.
```

Now I want to know if I change the `express.Router()` with simply `express()` in both `cars.js` and `animals.js` file, it'll work because both acts as new instance of express() which we called mini-app. Then what is the use of new `express.Router()` object?

Aren't the same methods exposed in `express.Router()` object, with their functionality, achievable via multiple `express()` instance like modular router handlers etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simplest terms, Router is a lightweight version of the express app, or [as Express docs put it](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router), a mini express application.

The global express object comes with many more resources to support views and various settings while the router basically provides the routing APIs like `.use`, `.get`, `.param`, and `route`. A router object represents an isolated instance of middleware and routes and is only capable of performing middleware and routing functions, which makes it perfect for efficiently modularizing your route handling.

> Now I want to know if I change the `express.Router()` with simply `express()` in both cars.js and animals.js file, it'll work because both act as new instance of express() which we called mini-app. Then what is the use of new `express.Router()` object?

Well, you should still be able to use `express()` instead of `express.Router()` for isolated routing purposes but with that you are also bringing much extra code that you probably won't use so it's an unnecessary overhead.

That is why the `express.Router()` was created: to provide route modularization without the overhead of creating an additional app.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I think for unnecessary overhead is not valid because it doesn't matter how many times `require('express')` is called (it's cached from nodejs doc) in the same project.

Comment: The caching makes the creation of the app happen once so all further requires are faster but that doesn't change the fact that the cached app still holds a lot of extra code that you wouldn't probably need just for routing.